# Grouping in informatica powercenter

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

I have a table with 4 columns (member, level, group, group_level). Group_level is currently empty and I am trying to populate Group_level from a measurement of the group’s different levels.

To calculate each member’s Group_level, I need to first group each member by his or her group column. From this group, I need to analyze the different levels in the group, and then populate the Group_level. For example:

```
member | level | group | group_level
-------|-------|-------|------------
1      | low   | 2     | med
2      | low   | 1     | low
3      | med   | 2     | med
```

I have the IIF statement worked out, but I’m stuck on trying to understand how to group these guys together. I am very new to informatica, so overly detailed instructions is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a 2nd instance of the source to the mapping.
2. Drag `level` and `group` to an aggregator.
3. Group by `group` and write an expression to calculate `group_level`.
4. Join this new data stream with the main one on `group`.